# Java NIO - How to efficiently parse a file containing both ascii and binary data?

Tags: java, nio

I have some data files looking something like this:

```
text
header
"lots of binary data hear"
/header
more text
header
"more binary data"
/header
....
```

Most of the files are around 1-5MB in size. It's very unlikely that I will have to deal with any files larger than approximately 30MB.

I'm fairly new to Java NIO and the API looks a bit like a jungle to me. Could anyone give me any pointers to how I should go about parsing a file like this?

Would it be possible to have multiple threads consuming data from different parts of the file? The file will just be open for reading.

Comment: Do you have any control over the file format?

Answer (score 2):

Redesign the file. That's a terrible design.

Answer (score 1):

Question is how would you know if you're reading text or binary data. If there is a clear demarcation of the text and binary regions (like a marker, or a defined block size), then I suspect [Preon](http://preon.codehaus.org/) would be able to help you out. Preon does have support for reading both text and binary data in a useful way. And since I'm pretty sure your binary data represents something else, you might also be able to decode the binary bits into a more useful data structure than just an array.

Answer (score 0):

you can `FileChannel.map()`, and read it like an array.

Comment: That just puts the file in memory. ByteBuffer has the almost the same methods as the result of FileChannel.map().